# Syntax error creating an SQL query dynamically

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I'm using VB6 and MS Access. my sql command is

```
insert into BatchInfo (BName,BDate,Currency) values('" & Me.txtBatchName.Text & "','" & Me.dtpBatchDate.Value & "','" & Me.cboCurrency.Text & "')
```

the output of the command at run time is

```
"insert into BatchInfo (BName,BDate,Currency) values('batch1','8/2/2012','AED')"
```

here is the schema of the BatchInfo Table

```
BatchID   AutoNumber
BName     Text
BDate     Date/Time
Currency  Text
```

I cannot find any syntax error. Please help.

Comment: If you're going to build up SQL strings, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE sanitise your database input otherwise you WILL [get problems](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Currency` is a reserved word, escape it thusly;

```
insert into BatchInfo (BName, BDate, [Currency]) values (...
```

Answer (score 2):

MS Access typically likes `#` signs around its dates:

```
insert into BatchInfo (BName,BDate,Currency) 
values('" & Me.txtBatchName.Text & "','#" & Me.dtpBatchDate.Value & "#','" & Me.cboCurrency.Text & "')
```

Comment: @Deanna I would strongly suggest year, month, day formats (yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd) rather than American, especially for people in non-US locales.

Comment: @Remou So would I wth any other RDBMS. [Access (and VB6, and VBA, etc) explicitly expect `#mm/dd/yyyy#`](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html#Format).

Comment: I am sorry but Allen Browne is not telling the whole story in this case, a very rare thing for Allen Browne. Access does indeed use American dates as default which leads to problems for people based in other locales, but what Access needs is an unambiguous date, and 4 digit year, month, day is the most unambiguous date that you can get.

Comment: Sadly MSDN is failing me and I can;t find a definitive reference, but this page on [query criteria](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010341674.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010341468#_Toc262850672) uses #mm/dd/yyyy# in the examples examples.

Comment: One of the problems for people working in non-US locales is that Access does not always need a US date, for example, in the query design window (v.2010), if you type #2012/07/05# Access itself it will change it to #05/07/2012#, not #07/05/2012#, so people working outside US locale are generally best using year,month,day. It is far less confusing for everyone.

Comment: Maybe Access has changed to be more sensible since I learnt it :) I try and steer clear of all database programming now.

Comment: The problem is that a vast amount of the writing is by people working with US locales. I have been using Access for more years than I would care to mention in non-US locales, but I can dig up some relevant quotes for you later, if you need them.

Comment: The problem is that all dates are numbers and how they are written out  is a function of your environment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14939/discussion-between-deanna-and-remou)

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes, not double quotes.

Try this

```
insert into BatchInfo (BName,BDate,Currency) values(""" & Me.txtBatchName.Text & """,#" & Me.dtpBatchDate.Value & #",""" & Me.cboCurrency.Text & """)
```

Comment: but this statement works fine. `"insert into Admission_Master values('" & id & "','" & Me.txtstdcode.Text & "','" & Me.cmbcourse.Text & "','" & modules & "','" & Me.dtpadmtd.Value & "','" & cfees1 & "','" & Me.dtpsdt.Value & "','" & Me.dtpedt.Value & "','N/A'," & CBool(False) & ",'" & cfees1 & "')"`

Comment: Some RDBMS accept both `'` and `"` delimeters. Others (e.g. mysql) only likes one of them

Comment: I've always just used double quotes "" in Access. Good to know there's another way.